# How Long Time Should I Wait For Google Analytics' Real Time Data in my Android App

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

Below lines are my Google Analytics v4 settings. Everything look correct. App works correct but I cant see real time  and other data on Google Analytics Console. Why?

**GoogleAnal.java**

```
public class GoogleAnal extends Application {
    public GoogleAnal() {
        super();
        }
    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();


    synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            if(trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER){
                Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
                mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
            }         
        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
....
....
....
Tracker t = ((GoogleAnal) this.getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
t.setScreenName("Screen1");

}

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }
```

Comment: Real-time Google Analytics, in my experience, takes a maximum of 60s to be seen. The current library version is bundled with GooglePlayServices, which are v6 now BTW.

Comment: so how should re-build my app?

Comment: How long ago did you create the Google analytics account?  It can take up to 24 -72 hours for a new account to start recording data.  Real-time should show your data within seconds.

Comment: Problem is here. I cant get real-time data